# Vue.js open and close hamburger menu

Tags: vue.js, menu, navigation-drawer

I made a navigation-drawer with two methods, one to open and one to close it. Unfortunately, they aren't working. When I click the button to open the navigation-drawer it's working but then I can't close it by clicking the cross.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="navigationdrawer">
       <span v-on:click="openNav()" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;">&#9776;</span>

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" v-on:onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a v-bind:href="link1">{{ name1 }}</a>
            <a v-bind:href="link2">{{ name2 }}</a>
            <a v-bind:href="link3">{{ name3 }}</a>
            <a v-bind:href="link4">{{ name4 }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
export default {
        name: 'NavigationDrawer',
        props: {
            msg: String,
            name1: String,
            name2: String,
            name3: String,
            name4: String,
            link1: String,
            link2: String,
            link3: String,
            link4: String
        },

        methods: {
            openNav() {
                document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '12%'
            },
            closeNav() {
                document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0%'
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: it's not `v-on:onclick` rather as you put it in the first function just `v-on:click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not `v-on:onclick` rather as you put it in the first function just `v-on:click`. Also you can use shorthand `@click="someFunc"`, in addition you don't invoke the function rather you would just put in the event handler, like so:
`@click="openNav"`